# ListView with ImageButton and Text

Tags: java, android, listview

I try to make a listview with imagebutton and text. Somehow my app crashed when I run it. I need someone can go through my log to see the mistakes I have made. Please help as I have zero background of coding.

Here is my main_java = IngredientChoices.java

```
public class IngredientChoices extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView lv;

String[] category_titles={"Baking Goods", "Beverages/Alcohol", "Dairy", "Fruit", "Herbs & Spices", "Meat", "Nuts & Seeds", "Pasta, Breads & Grains", "Poultry", "Sauces, Soup & Condiments", "Seafood", "Vegetables"};
int [] category_icons={R.drawable.bakingood,R.drawable.beverages, R.drawable.dairy, R.drawable.apple, R.drawable.herbs, R.drawable.meat, R.drawable.nuts, R.drawable.bread, R.drawable.poultry, R.drawable.soup, R.drawable.seafood, R.drawable.vegetable};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ingredient_choices);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    //Adapter

    IngredientCategoryAdapter adapter = new IngredientCategoryAdapter(this, category_titles, category_icons);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), category_titles[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });



}
}
```

Here is my adapter.java

```
public class IngredientCategoryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

// Declarations
int[] category_icons={};
String[] category_titles={};
Context c;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public IngredientCategoryAdapter(Context context, String[]      category_title, int[] category_icon) {
    super(context, R.layout.ingcategory_list_view, category_title);

    this.c=context;
    this.category_icons=category_icons;
    this.category_titles=category_titles;

}

public class ViewHolder {

    TextView category_title;
    ImageButton category_icon;
}

@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView==null){
        inflater= (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.ingcategory_list_view, null);
    }

    //our viewholder object

    final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

    // Initialize our views
    holder.category_title= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.category_title);
    holder.category_icon=(ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.category_icon);

    //Assign data

    holder.category_icon.setImageResource(category_icons[position]);
    holder.category_title.setText(category_titles[position]);


    return convertView;
}
}
```

Thank you!

crash log

> 03-08 15:23:17.545 8166-8224/? E/BooksSync: Soft error
>                                               com.google.android.apps.books.net.HttpHelper$AuthIoException: 403: Forbidden
>                                               Request: GET https://encrypted.google.com/books?cp_activate=2%3AC4q8DQZi0PFAsa4LWbLehD8AAAA6gAd6-baW_r-qDKNVNPTjsycPW8Iqe-VhNJcXNKhi02FNTv6sb_oW-B67bwycWnmqttWYrKqXuC56--BtZlv5 HTTP/1.1
>   03-08 15:23:17.555 8166-8224/? E/BooksSync: Sync error
>                                               com.google.android.apps.books.net.HttpHelper$AuthIoException: 403: Forbidden
>                                               Request: GET https://encrypted.google.com/books?cp_activate=2%3AC4q8DQZi0PFAsa4LWbLehD8AAAA6gAd6-baW_r-qDKNVNPTjsycPW8Iqe-VhNJcXNKhi02FNTv6sb_oW-B67bwycWnmqttWYrKqXuC56--BtZlv5 HTTP/1.1
>   03-08 15:23:20.418 1281-1281/? E/LSO: LSO Service is not yet ready!!!
>   03-08 15:23:20.518 1281-1281/? E/SoundPool: error loading /system/media/audio/ui/lens_flare_tap.ogg
>   03-08 15:23:20.518 1281-1281/? E/SoundPool: error loading /system/media/audio/ui/lens_flare_unlock.ogg
>   03-08 15:23:20.758 300-18933/? E/AwesomePlayer: LPAPlayer::Clip duration setting of less than 30sec not supported, defaulting to 60sec
>   03-08 15:23:20.758 300-18933/? E/AwesomePlayer: LPAPlayer::Clip duration setting of less than 30sec not supported, defaulting to 60sec
>   03-08 15:23:20.958 300-19477/? E/AwesomePlayer: LPAPlayer::Clip duration setting of less than 30sec not supported, defaulting to 60sec
>   03-08 15:23:20.958 300-19477/? E/AwesomePlayer: LPAPlayer::Clip duration setting of less than 30sec not supported, defaulting to 60sec
>   03-08 15:23:22.050 8338-8338/? E/Diag_Lib:  Diag_LSM_Init: Failed to open handle to diag driver, error = 2
>   03-08 15:23:23.571 8267-8267/? E/SMD: smd_init start 
>   03-08 15:23:23.571 8267-8267/? E/SMD: smd Interface open failed errno is 2 -1
>   03-08 15:23:24.332 884-1422/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 10416
>   03-08 15:23:24.572 8267-8267/? E/SMD: smd Interface open failed errno is 2 -1
>   03-08 15:23:25.573 8267-8267/? E/SMD: smd Interface open failed errno is 2 -1
>   03-08 15:23:26.574 8267-8267/? E/SMD: smd Interface open failed errno is 2 -1
>   03-08 15:23:27.505 8339-8339/? E/Diag_Lib:  Diag_LSM_Init: Failed to open handle to diag driver, error = 2
>   03-08 15:23:27.565 8267-8267/? E/
>   03-08 15:24:00.677 884-2563/? E/PersonaManagerService: inState():  stateMachine is null !!
>   03-08 15:24:01.058 8434-8434/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                    Process: com.example.cassieleong.delishcart, PID: 8434
>                                                    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
>                                                        at com.example.cassieleong.delishcart.IngredientCategoryAdapter.getView(IngredientCategoryAdapter.java:59)
>                                                        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2823)
>                                                        at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1290)
>                                                        at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1202)
>                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
>                                                        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
>                                                        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:464)
>                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
>                                                        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:610)
>                                                        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:677)
>                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
>                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
>                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
>                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
>                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1435)
>                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:721)
>                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:612)
>                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
>                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
>                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
>                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1435)
>                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:721)
>                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:612)
>                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
>                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2897)
>                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2248)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1306)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1548)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1191)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6642)
>                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
>                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
>                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
>                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
>   03-08 15:24:01.448 884-8480/? E/android.os.Debug: !@Dumpstate > sdumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
>   03-08 15:24:01.578 8267-8267/? E/SMD: smd Interface open failed errno is 2 -1
>   03-08 15:24:02.579 8267-8267/? E/SMD: smd Interface open failed errno is 2 -1
>   03-08 15:24:02.639 8503-8503/? E/Diag_Lib:  Diag_LSM_Init: Failed to open handle to diag driver, error = 2
>   03-08 15:24:03.580 8267-8267/? E/SMD: smd Interface open failed errno is 2 -1
>   03-08 15:24:04.581 8267-8267/? E/SMD: smd Interface open failed errno is 2 -1
>   03-08 15:24:05.592 8267-8267/? E/SMD: smd Interface open failed errno is 2 -1
>   03-08 15:24:06.593 8267-8267/? E/SMD: smd Interface open failed errno is 2 -1
>   03-08 15:24:07.594 8267-8267/? E/SMD: smd Interface open failed errno is 2 -1

Comment: Can you paste the crash logs please ?

Comment: I have edited the post. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem sometimes to get resources without context in android. Try to change:

```
holder.category_icon.setImageResource(category_icons[position]);
```

to

```
holder.category_icon.setImageDrawable(c.getResources().getDrawable(category_icons[position]));
```

EDIT: ok, it seems one (or both) of your arrays is empty. Try to pu the data right before you initialize your adapter in `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`

like

```
ListView lv;

String[] category_titles;
int [] category_icons;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ingredient_choices);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    category_titles = {"Baking Goods", "Beverages/Alcohol", "Dairy", "Fruit", "Herbs & Spices", "Meat", "Nuts & Seeds", "Pasta, Breads & Grains", "Poultry", "Sauces, Soup & Condiments", "Seafood", "Vegetables"};
    category_icons={R.drawable.bakingood,R.drawable.beverages, R.drawable.dairy, R.drawable.apple, R.drawable.herbs, R.drawable.meat, R.drawable.nuts, R.drawable.bread, R.drawable.poultry, R.drawable.soup, R.drawable.seafood, R.drawable.vegetable}
    //Adapter

    IngredientCategoryAdapter adapter = new IngredientCategoryAdapter(this, category_titles, category_icons);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: holder.category_icon.setImageDrawable(c.getResources().getDrawable(category_icons[position])); - the getDrawable get crossed out automatically and it crashed still. = (

Comment: can you put the log of the crash here please?

Comment: I have added the crah log in the post. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your adapter constructor.
Change your adapter exactly to:

```
public IngredientCategoryAdapter(Context context, String[] category_title, int[] category_icon) {
    super(context, R.layout.ingcategory_list_view, category_title);

    this.c=context;
    this.category_icons=category_icon;
    this.category_titles=category_title;
}
```